# Rename [caramelisation] to [caramelization]

Tags: discussion, tags

Since I believe this site uses US spellings like most SE sites, and to match the users's actual usage within the questions, I propose that we merge [caramelisation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caramelisation) over to [caramelization](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caramelization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not.

29 questions affected, synonym created.